# requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: exception code is here]

when using Image-Picker package and run ,this exception is showing . image is not shows in the container after taking the image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside needing to add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.yyy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
</manifest>
```

You also need **Runtime Request Permission**, by using [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package:

```
import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';

PermissionStatus permissionResult = await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission. WriteExternalStorage);
if (permissionResult == PermissionStatus.authorized){
  // code of read or write file in external storage (SD card)
}
```

Note:

1. when running `SimplePermissions.requestPermission` for the **First Time**， app will pop up a window, you **MUST** click `ALLOW`:

[image]

to give permission.

2. If you already clicked `DENY`, then uninstall debug app and re-debug it to install and fix this -> trigger the popup window and give you chance to click `ALLOW`.

Comment: which file need to add runtime request permission

Comment: Sorry, https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler use This package to get access file write and read.

Comment: Didnt work the solution

Comment: please read https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler document there is example also.